# How to maintain the url for 404 page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-404, url-routing

We're working on an angularjs app, in which the user is able to publish his or her profile as a resumée.

So for instance if the user has a published profile the following url is valid:

```
www.page.com/public/johnsmith
```

However in case of

```
www.page.com/public/johnsmith2345
```

which isn't a public profile I would like to show a 404 page. The problem is that because of angular's routing I have to redirect to the 404 page, so the url will be rewritten as

```
www.page.com/404.
```

What would be the correct implementation to maintain the original url and even make it work in IE9?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this would be to deal with this in your controller/view. e.g.

```
$routeProvider.when('/public/:user', 
    {
        templateUrl: 'profile.html',
        controller: 'profileCtrl',
        resolve: {
            userProfile: {
                //Try and load the user's profile. Resolve null if the profile can't be found
            }
        }
    }
);

var profileCtrl = function($scope, userProfile) {
    $scope.userProfile = userProfile;
}
```

profile.html:

```
<div ng-if="!userProfile">
    <div ng-include="404page.html"></div>
</div>
<div ng-if="userProfile">
    ... Profile view here
</div>
```

Comment: Rob, that means that each and every route which is public, would have to have a `ng-if` with the 404.html page.

Comment: No ways. There must be a better way.